# SQL: Trying to add up a total row which was calculated from 2 other columns

Tags: sql, join, sum

I'm attempting, and partly done, to find out how much stock is left in a business.  I have a stock table and product price table that I'm pulling values from.  The TOTAL column is quantityinstock * price which is what I need but I'd like to the get an overall total of the TOTAL.

How would I go about this? I've been searching for quite a while now to no avail!

I would like to, if possible get a TOTAL of TOTAL row adding up all of the TOTAL i.e. 3551.13 + 2941.91 + 2713.19 = VALUE.

```
SELECT
A.productID,
    quantityInStock,
    productPrice,
    quantityInStock * productPrice AS TOTAL
FROM gs_stock A
JOIN gs_productprice B ON A.productID = B.productID
WHERE endDate IS NULL
GROUP BY A.productID
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

Sample Data:

```
+-----------+-----------------+--------------+---------+
| productID | quantityInStock | productPrice |  TOTAL  |
+-----------+-----------------+--------------+---------+
|        71 |             187 |        18.99 | 3551.13 |
|        73 |             109 |        26.99 | 2941.91 |
|        74 |             181 |        14.99 | 2713.19 |
+-----------+-----------------+--------------+---------+
```

```sql
SELECT
  A.productID,
  A.quantityInStock,
  B.productPrice,
  A.quantityInStock * B.productPrice AS TOTAL
FROM gs_stock A
JOIN gs_productprice B on A.productID = B.productID
WHERE endDate IS NULL
GROUP BY A.productID
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to total of (price * quantity)?

Comment: Please share your SQL as text. Please share sample data and desired results as well (as text) you can use a site like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to help format here (After pasting click the code `{}` button at the top of the editor to format properly.

Comment: Hi, apologies, new to Stack Overflow posting! I've updated with suggestions.  Looking to get a total of the TOTAL column.  Is it a subquery that is needed?

Comment: Trying to return two types of result 1) a total by product, and 2) a total overall, is not really best done in a subquery. It's pretty much always going to be two queries (see @MEDZ answer for the second query). Or, more normally add up the totals in your application when processing your initial result set above and output the total of totals in that logic

Comment: This is not clear about how the desired output is a function of input. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Please clarify via edits, not comments.  See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for the guidance. I'm new to both Stack Overflow and a novice SQL user.  Wasn't attempting to be difficult with my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood was that you need a total value of your stock that will be as follows:

```
SELECT
  sum(TOTAL) as TOTAL_SUM
FROM (
   SELECT
    A.productID,
    quantityInStock,
    productPrice,
    quantityInStock * productPrice AS TOTAL
   FROM gs_stock A
   JOIN gs_productprice B ON A.productID = B.productID
   WHERE endDate IS NULL
   GROUP BY A.productID
) TOTAL
```

Added in TOTAL following the end bracket which then gave me the required calculation I was looking for!!!  Cheers again, really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi, this doesn't really work for what I'm looking for, thank you for the advice though.

Comment: @cmc I do not know how my previous answer did not work. I've updated my answer though. Check it out and let me know

Comment: Thanks for this as it helped me get to the end result!